# GAE: Send email from any arbitrary email address in Google Apps domain

Tags: google-app-engine

Referring to the following document about sending email in Google App Engine:
   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

It says that the email sender (i.e., From address) may be:
   Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

This seems to be imply that as long as my domain mycompany.com is a Google Apps domain and I've added to my my Google Apps CPanel as a service, that I would be able to send an email from any arbitrary address that is not an existing user, such as: whatever@mycompany.com. Note that I do *not* have the app's authentication type set up as "Google Apps Domain" but rather as "Google Accounts API".

However, this is not working as such. I am only able to send email if it is an existing Google Apps user and is registered with the app as an administrator.

Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: The comment is about the kind of mail address, which can be used. But you always have to register this address in app engine to use it as a sender.

Comment: The reason I interpreted as implying that I would not need to register that exact email address as an administrator is that the document linked to above lists four bullet points of type of emails, and one of them is the "address of a registered administrator". This implies that the 4th one of "any valid receiving address of a domain account" means it is not registered.

Comment: Bottom line, I do not want to create another Google Apps user just to send email from "donotreply@mycompany.com". I guess I may need to use AWS SES with Boto to get that flexibility.

Comment: You do not have to register it as an administrator. You can use the viewer role.

Comment: I mean I do not want to have to create a Google Apps user (whatever role it gets registered as) just to send email.

Comment: I think you can use an Apps alias email address.

Comment: At the moment I prefer to use SES to send mail. Because App Engine does not give any feedback, when you send a mail. But after more then two years this problem will be fixed. See this famous issue : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800

Comment: I tried that. To invite an email address to collaborate on an application, it has to be an authenticated user for that email address. whatever@mycompany.com doesn't work, even if it's an alias for my email address.

Comment: On the issue you linked to, a Googler wrote last week that bounces are in QA now. Do you have any performance or reliability issues using SES since it's outside Google's datacenter?

Comment: I'am a great fan of App Engine. But for the mail I use SES and and this works fine, without any errors or maintenace.

Comment: Thanks. I switched over to using boto & django-ses (using django-nonrel). I did have to make the following modifications in django-ses to make it work on GAE: (1) https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses/issues/49; (2) https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses/issues/48

Comment: I do not use django and I do not use boto. I used the SES webservice : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800#c72

Comment: boto is just a python wrapper for the web service. I also am working on wrapping that in a task to unblock the request.

Answer (score 2):

You should continue reading right after the sentence you quoted:

`Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.
To send an email from an existing domain account, add the domain account as a Developer to your application using the Administration Console. The account is then sent an email with an invite to develop the application, which you must accept to add the account to the application.`

So you still need to add the domain user under GAE Admin -> Permissions.